# Hiding elements selectively or replacing them with empty boxes

Tags: draft

Is there any package or environment that allows to substitute **whatever you want** in your output with empty boxes of the same size, like you do with `documentclass`' or some packages' `draft` option for images and some other things?

One approach is to write inside `\textcolor{white}{}` but that only works "visually" and if you don't need to include commands as `\section{}` inside.

If there is no built solution yet, maybe using `ifdraft` package?

The idea is to hide parts selectively while keeping the appearance of the layout, and... maybe saving some time when compiling very large documents? The `\input{}` solution, for example, is not a solution: if you want to print only the middle paragraph in p3 it would appear in fist page's top.

Comment: Related [1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108646/hide-paragraph-but-keep-space) and [2](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43069/how-to-replace-a-large-block-of-text-by-an-empty-block-of-the-same-size)

Comment: It is hard to do this and allow line/page breaking and any possible approach I can think of would take _longer_ rather than less time as it would involve measuring and potentially multiple runs to figure out where the text would have gone.

Comment: So not less run time. But maybe something to at least just superimpose a white box over the elements?

Comment: If Bruno's answer in your 2nd link doesn't answer this you'll need to give more detail ("Just" isn't the word I'd use, it is very hard to do this in TeX:-)

Comment: [Another related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22803/exclude-everything-from-pdf-document-except-images)

Comment: Instead of `\textcolor{white}{}`, you could just use `\color{white}`.  This approach will work across section boundaries.  To undo it, just enter `\color{black}`.  Of course, no compilation time is saved here.